# Parsing html using HtmlAgilityPack in C# for a cross-platform Xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse an online calendar to have the events posted on that calendar display in my cross-platform app. This is the code that I have so far.

```
 var html = @"http://html-agility-pack.net/";
 HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 var htmlDoc = web.LoadFromWebAsync(html);
 HtmlNodeCollection node=htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
```

The error I am getting is:

"'Task HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for "DocumentNode' and no extension method 'DocumentNode' accepting a first argument of type 'Task HtmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

I installed HtmlAgilityPack using the NuGet package manager in Xamarin so it is in my references for the entire project and I am using "using HtmlAgilityPack;" I viewed the HAP in the object browser and there is clearly a "DocumentNode"property which is why I am confused as to why it doesn't think there is.

I don't know what it is that I am missing, please help.

Comment: you need to `await` the `LoadFromWebAsync()` method.

Comment: This is one of the pitfalls of using `var` to define variables - you sometimes assume the type is something other than what it is. `Task<Abc>` is completely different that `Abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use await when calling an async method

```
// htmlDoc is a Task<HtmlDocument>
var htmlDoc = web.LoadFromWebAsync(html);

// htmlDoc is a HtmlDocument
var htmlDoc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(html);
```